# Why do we have to add "@objc" in front of "func" in Swift 4 when dealing with target/action selectors?

Tags: swift, swift4

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In Swift 3, this is the code

```
func test() { }
```

but in Swift 4 and Xcode 9 you have to write it like this:

```
@objc func test() { }
```

Why is that?